# Exponential voltage source Pspice

Tags: voltage, pspice, orcad

I want to put an exponential voltage source in Orcad / Pspice that \$V(t) = e^t\$.

I used Vexp and I don't know how to set \$V1, V2, Td1, Td2, Tc1, Tc2\$.
I found an equation $$V(t)= V1+(V2-V1)((1-e^\frac{(-time-Td1)}{Tc1} )-(1-e^\frac{(-time-Td2)}{Tc2} ))$$
for $$V(t)=e^t $$
I set \$V1=0v , V2=-1v ,Tc1 =-1 ,Td1=Td2=Tc2=0\$ to so by equation I get 
$$V(t)= (-1)((1-e^\frac{(-time)}{-1} )-(1-e^\frac{(-time)}{0} ))=e^{time}$$
but when i put Voltage probe to find graph it doesn't show the correct result.
Does anybody know how should I set the settings to get \$e^t\$ ?

Comment: Why are you using a negative time constant? Or even a null one? If you look closely, `Tc1` and `Tc2` are at the *denominator*.

Comment: to get e^t . what should I use to get that ?

Comment: There may be internal limiting for negative, or zero valued time constants. Better use a behavioural source for that. Though I can't be sure for PSpice, LTspice seems to allow those values and get the correct output.

Comment: Thanks but we have to use PSpice.